# Getting array element with a sequence error while building model using GBC from sparse matrix

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, decision-tree

I am getting  below error building a classifier model from sparse matrix data frame .

**Error**

```
C:\Users\AshokEapen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**My code**

```
 cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 5000,analyzer='word') 
 tf = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))
 for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(tf[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)
    train = data.drop(['Stop_Type','Co_Name','Cust_ID','Phone','Shpr_ID','Resi_Cnt','Buz_Cnt','Nearby_Cnt','parseNumber','removeString','Qty','bins','Co_Name_Flag'], axis=1)
    Y = data['Resi']

    gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth = 7, n_estimators=1500, min_samples_leaf=10)

    print('Training GBC')

    #fit classifier, look for best
    gbc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How can I resolve this?
 PLease find below the  splitted data frame of train
**X_train**

```
    Lat Lng Weight  Resi_Ratio  Resi_Area   Product categorizeNumber    ResiR   bins_qty    ab  ... yi  yin ying    yip yiu yu  yue yuen    yuet    yuk
49291   22.334624   114.195812  0.23    1.000000    U   IE  Mobile  0.67646 1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
43012   22.373704   114.106212  0.50    0.014925    N   IP  undefined   0.162105    1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3237    22.268394   114.129232  1.55    0.050000    N   IP  Landline    0.105263    1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
52313   22.339494   114.148902  0.30    0.011538    N   IP  undefined   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Y_train**

```
Out[37]:
4987     N
47455    N
31422    N
44714    N
56879    N
26408    N
43667    N
18978    N
39741    N
20614    Y
6660     N
35500    N
57861    N
12971    N
35515    N
41007    N
58319    Y
51216    N
5292     N
26321    Y
12624    N
21936    N
29168    Y
```

Updated the with X_train and Y_train

Answer (score 0):

First off I am assuming you mean your `X` data is in sparse format, not your `y`.

If you take a look at the source in [`sklearn/utils/validation.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d657eb4268ac20c4db01c48065b5a1bfe80d/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L378-L382) you will see that your error is the else section of an if ... else statement that first checks if the passed array is sparse (and in this case of format 'coo', 'csr', or 'csc').

Therefore it would seem that your `X` data is not in one of those formats.

Comment: Both  X_train and y_train are pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: Can you post a small excerpt of what they look like?

Comment: Updated in question section

Comment: Have you tried passing just the values of X and y (i.e. as arrays)?